# Trying to break an exim mail loop

Tags: linux, debian, email, exim

One of our servers is getting stuck in mail loops with exim. It looks like it started with cron jobs that all send their email to "root@somedomain.com". This hits a mail relay server somewhere else in our organization, which I guess sends it back to my team's server, since it hosts "somedomain.com". I think this is where the loop starts, it looks like when the message is received, it gets sent back to the relay, though I'm not sure why. Eventually, the messages end up as "frozen" with a mail loop message:

> Too many "Received" headers - suspected mail loop

The first step I'm planning to take is not having cron send messages to root (there's now a separate address on a different domain for that), but I'm concerned that won't actually fix the root cause of the loop, and I'd like to fix it properly in case someone else creates a job or script on this server in the future that mails root@somedomain.

I'm not familiar with exim (or mail server management in general), and to my knowledge, this "used to" work, and something (config? version update? other?) may have changed that preceded this mail loop, but it does not seem to be known what that might have been.

Comment: Check the relevant DNS records. Also check that the host is not named with the naked domain name.

Comment: __Always__ check the _Received_ headers first, they should provide a hunt what the real addresses were.